# Is it possible to construct a sequence using the first $n$ prime numbers such that each segment has a unique sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

For example, consider the sequence $2,7,3,5$. The sums of the segments of this sequence are as follows, and they are all unique:
$$2, 2+7, 2+7+3, 2+7+3+5, 7, 7+3, 7+3+5, 3, 3+5, 5$$
Can we generate such a sequence using the first $n$ prime numbers for any given $n$?

Here's my attempt:

Initially, consider the case of natural numbers instead of prime numbers. It can be shown that we cannot construct such a sequence when $n\geq 4$. This is because the sum of natural numbers up to $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which equals the number of segments. Therefore, there exist segments whose sum is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-2$, and we need both $1$ and $2$ at the ends. Considering the neighbors of $1$, since the sum of the number and $1$ cannot be $1$ to $n$, the neighbor must be $n$. Similarly, the neighbor of $2$ must be $n-1$, but $2+(n-1)=n+1$, which coincides with the neighbor of $1$.

I also searched for the case of odd numbers using a computer, and found that we can construct a sequence for odd numbers up to $29$, but we cannot construct a set of odd numbers from $1$ to $31$.

Additionally, I conducted a computer search for the case of prime numbers and found that we can construct a sequence for prime numbers up to $n\leq40$. Here are the results, showcasing the construction of the smallest sequence in lexicographical order. However, upon examining this outcome, it appears that the sequence tends to grow larger in lexicographical order as $n$ increases, suggesting the possibility that we may not be able to construct such a sequence at some point.

```
2
2 3
2 5 3
2 7 3 5
2 7 3 5 11
2 7 3 5 11 13
2 7 3 11 5 13 17
2 7 3 11 17 5 13 19
2 7 3 17 5 13 23 19 11
2 7 3 23 5 17 19 11 13 29
2 7 3 23 11 13 19 29 31 5 17
2 7 3 23 13 5 29 11 17 37 31 19
2 7 3 23 13 11 19 37 31 29 5 17 41
2 7 3 23 13 11 31 41 29 5 17 43 19 37
2 7 3 23 13 17 37 5 19 47 11 41 29 31 43
2 7 3 23 13 19 31 11 41 53 29 43 47 37 17 5
2 7 3 23 13 19 31 11 29 53 17 5 59 47 41 43 37
2 7 3 23 13 19 31 29 11 5 61 53 59 41 47 17 37 43
2 7 3 23 13 29 31 19 5 47 41 53 61 43 67 11 59 17 37
2 7 3 23 13 29 31 19 5 59 41 61 17 53 37 43 67 71 11 47
2 7 3 23 13 29 37 17 41 43 31 61 67 19 71 59 47 73 5 11 53
2 7 3 23 13 29 41 11 5 53 31 19 73 67 79 47 43 61 17 37 59 71
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 17 37 41 83 67 79 31 19 71 61 73 11 59 47 53 5
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 47 17 59 89 83 67 71 53 5 61 37 73 79 11 41
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 53 11 79 73 67 89 71 41 61 5 83 59 47 97 37 17
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 53 11 5 97 83 73 101 71 41 47 89 59 67 61 37 17 79
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 59 5 53 97 103 101 73 89 17 83 71 11 41 61 67 79 47 37
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 59 5 53 47 79 97 83 71 107 101 89 17 37 61 67 73 11 41 103
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 67 17 11 41 107 101 97 83 89 103 59 37 109 5 73 79 61 71 53 47
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 19 31 67 17 11 59 89 107 73 71 53 47 109 37 113 79 103 97 41 101 61 5 83
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 5 11 53 17 59 67 97 103 113 109 73 83 101 79 89 61 41 37 107 71 127 19 31
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 5 11 53 17 59 71 109 103 19 31 67 97 131 127 79 83 113 41 101 107 37 89 61 73
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 31 61 37 17 79 73 97 5 71 83 131 109 113 67 89 59 103 19 107 127 101 137 53 41 11
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 31 67 17 11 53 5 137 71 101 79 103 19 127 109 139 83 107 37 59 97 131 89 113 41 61 73
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 31 67 17 11 53 5 137 113 107 97 71 89 101 109 131 83 73 103 37 19 127 149 59 41 61 139 79
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 31 67 17 11 53 61 79 73 137 113 71 59 109 103 139 151 101 127 149 89 131 5 83 107 37 97 19 41
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 31 67 17 11 53 5 83 137 149 89 71 59 131 97 107 73 61 79 139 109 113 101 151 103 157 37 127 19 41
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 47 53 5 11 71 41 61 113 17 89 73 139 157 163 107 59 83 109 37 101 137 31 149 97 103 151 19 67 131 127 79
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 53 37 79 5 11 47 41 89 137 101 139 167 83 113 31 163 71 151 107 109 97 127 73 157 61 131 59 17 149 103 67 19
2 7 3 23 13 29 43 61 19 37 59 47 41 11 131 73 97 89 107 101 31 137 167 139 163 109 149 173 151 127 79 103 157 17 67 113 53 83 71 5
```

Comment: Interesting ! (+1)